# If $\{a_n\}$ is a positive sequence and $b_n := a_1/a_2 + \dotsb + a_{n-1}/a_n + a_n/a_1$, then show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence.

We define $b_n$ as following:

$$b_n = \frac{a_1}{a_2} + \frac{a_2}{a_3} + \ldots + \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} + \frac{a_n}{a_1}$$

**Question:** Prove that $\lim b_n=\infty$.

---

**My suggested solution:** I was able to prove the opposite (that the limit is not infinity), may you show me what I did wrong?

I took $a_n$ as following: $1,1,2,8,64,1024,\dots$
Then $b_n$ is:
$$1/1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + \dotsb + a_n.$$
The first elements except the last are the sum of a geometric progression which converges to $2$ when $n$ gets too big so the overall limit is $2+a_n$ which isn't infinity for sure...

Comment: Hem, does $2+2^n$ not tend to infinity for sure ?

Comment: Your geometric series does not include the last term, which spoils your convergence argument.

Answer (score 6):

In your counterexample something doesn't work, indeed you are assuming

$$\large {a_n=2^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}}}\to \infty$$

and therefore

$$b_n= \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + a_n\ge a_n \to \infty$$

To prove that $b_n \to \infty$, by AM-GM we have that

$$b_n = \frac{a_1}{a_2} + \frac{a_2}{a_3} + \ldots + \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} + \frac{a_n}{a_1} \ge n \sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1}{a_2} \cdot \frac{a_2}{a_3} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \cdot \frac{a_n}{a_1}}=n\cdot 1=n\to \infty$$

then conclude by squeeze theorem.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, I am asking about what is wrong with my solution...

Comment: @ArielCohen I've added some observation about your solution according to other indications given in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

We can write

$$b_n=c_1+c_2+c_3+\cdots c_{n-1}+\frac1{c_1c_2c_3\cdots c_{n-1}}$$ where the $c_k$ are positive numbers.

The minimum value of $b_n$ is found by cancelling the gradient,

$$\forall k:1-\frac1{c_1c_2c_3\cdots c_{n-1}c_k}=0$$ or $$c_k=\frac1{c_1c_2c_3\cdots c_{n-1}}=\frac1p.$$

The solution is $p=c_k=1$ and $b_n=n$ is the smallest possible sum, as found independently by @user.